# How To Make Dynamic HTML Selected Option With PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have this HTML select options :

```
<select>
<option>Married</option>
<option>Single</option>
<option>In a relationship</option>
<option>Forever Alone</option>
</select>
```

and selected option is based on MySQL result, for example if `$row['status'] = Married` then `<option selected>Married</option>` and the other options doesn't have 'selected' word on the option tag.

how to make this dynamic selected option?

Comment: Are the options stored in the database as well?

Comment: on the database there's a column named 'status' and that column's type is ENUM ("Married", "Single", "In a relationship", "Forever alone"). and what stored in that column is what user's already selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example:

```
// these can also come from a database
$statuses = array( 'Married', 'Single', 'In a relationship' );

foreach ( $statuses as $status ) {
    echo '<option' . ( $row['status'] == $status ? ' selected' : '' ) . '>';
    echo $status;
    echo '</option>';
}
```

Comment: bro, your code only produce what's selected, right? what if the selected option is 'Single' and I still want to display all the options : Married, In a realtionship and Single itself?

Comment: This isn't valid XHTML if XHTML is used; ' selected' should be ' selected="selected"'

Comment: @RobertHanson - This will display the other options properly

Comment: @GlaciesofPacis : you're right... I didn't notice that... thanks!